# Efficient approach to verifying that the only real solutions to this system of quadratic equations are trivial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations

Let $a,b,c,d,e,f$ be real numbers. In the course of my research, I've arrived at the following system of equations \begin{eqnarray*}
a+d+f &=& 0, \\
ad + af + df - b^2 - c^2 - e^2 &=& 0 \\
ae^2 + c^2 d - 2bc - adf &=& 0.
\end{eqnarray*}

Inserting this into Wolfram, we get some unwieldy expressions, but all of them require that one of these numbers is complex.

> Is there an efficient method for proving directly that the only real solution to this system of equations is the trivial one?

Comment: To bolster the computational case: If you set up this system of equations in Mathematica, then the `FindInstance` command cannot find two real solutions (it does find the trivial one). That's not a mathematical proof but it does mean that Mathematica fails to find any nontrivial solution. (Code: `FindInstance[{a+d+f==0,a d+d f+ a f==b^2+c^2+e^2,a e^2+c^2 d==2 b c+a d f},{a,b,c,d,e,f},Reals,2]`.)

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you for your comment. I'm not following, what is the implication of the failure of homogeneity?

Comment: @Semiclassical Thank you, this is a great check :)

Comment: One approach that's occasionally used for such polynomial systems, though I don't know how useful it would be here, is the sum of squares method. The idea is to show that a solution of this system of equations would imply that $a_1 f_1^2+a_2 f_2^2+\cdot +a_k f_k^2 =0$, where the $f_k$ are linear functions of the 6 variables. But the left-hand side can only be true if all the linear functions vanish identically, which is easy to test for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Squaring the first equation you get

$$a^2 + d^2 + f^2 + 2ad + 2af + 2df = 0.$$

Substituting in the second one gives

$$\tfrac12 a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + \tfrac12 d^2 + e^2 + \tfrac12 f^2 = 0,$$

but this is possible only when all the variables are equal to $0$.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you :)

Comment: This looks to be an example of the sum-of-squares method I indicated in comments. Well-spotted!

Comment: Another way to have seen this result, though it looks less elegant: Eliminating $f$ from the second equation via the first, we have $a^2+c^2+ad+d^2+e^2+b^2=0$. But $a^2+ad+d^2=\frac12 a^2+\frac12 (a+d)^2+\frac12 d^2$, so the equation amounts to a sum of squares and has only trivial solution.